# php RarArchive & file_get_contents

Tags: php, rar

I need open rar archive, search all ***.txt** files, read this files and put content in php array

```
$file="archive.rar";
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$tmp=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tmp';

if($ext=='rar'){
    $archive = RarArchive::open($file);
    $entries = $archive->getEntries();
    foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        echo file_get_contents($entry->getName());// not working
        $entry->extract($tmp);
    }
    $archive->close();  
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to 'put content in php array' ?

Comment: i want read all readme.txt files and publish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`RarEntry::getName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/rarentry.getname.php) method returns only path *relative to archive*. The [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function knows nothing about this archive and it just try to find a regular file in current directory. You can use the [`rar://`](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.rar.php) protocol wrapper according to format:

```
rar://<url encoded archive name>[*][#[<url encoded entry name>]]
```

e.g.

```
echo file_get_contents('rar://' . $file . '#' . $entry->getName());
```